# Dynamically setting user task assignee

Tags: activiti

I have to create process in activiti which requires the following use case.

1.The form has a people search field
2.When someone completes the form and completes the task with a people search field filled with names,I need to set the next task's assigned with the name/names as users who can take action on the next task.

How can I achieve using the activiti engine apis.

any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can use following steps:

1. Pass input user value from your html form to Activiti using `taskService.complete(task.getId(), taskVariables);` taskVariables should contain variable with keys for example 'userId' or 'userIds' to access submitted values in process instance
2. Use expressions in your process definitions `<userTask id="task" name="My Task" activiti:assignee="${userId}"/>` or `<userTask id="task" name="My Task" activiti:candidateUsers="${userIds}"/>` to assign tasks 

   Also look to http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnUserTask and http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#springExpressions for detailed information

Comment: But it says Unknown property used in expression ${userIds}. What am i missing?

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan set variable `userIds` to process instead of passing it in `taskVariables`